# EditText not accepting ‘number’ input from keyboard in DialogFragment

Tags: android

I am using EditText to capture user input in form of number (frequency). I have an EditText inside a DialogFragment. But as you can see in the gif link below, the EditText with ‘android:inputType=number’ is not accepting numerical input from softkeybard. Please help!

[image]

Here is the code of the layout file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/add_dialog_title"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:text="@string/habit_name"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/habit_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="textCapWords" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_start_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/start_date"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:text="@string/start_date" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_number_of_times"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/times"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/number_of_times"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/save_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/save" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the Java code for this DialogFragment -

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;

import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.method.TextKeyListener;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import iamutkarshtiwari.github.io.habtrac.R;
import iamutkarshtiwari.github.io.habtrac.activity.models.HabitContract;
import iamutkarshtiwari.github.io.habtrac.activity.utils.HabitDbHelper;

public class AddHabitFragment extends DialogFragment {

    String mImageURI;

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        final View addView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add, null);


        final Dialog addDialog = builder.setView(addView)
                .create();



        addDialog.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(DialogInterface arg0, int keyCode,
                                 KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    AddHabitFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
//                    finish();
//                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        // Current date
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println("Current time => " + c.getTime());
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
        final TextView startDate = (TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        startDate.setText(formattedDate);


        // set on the listener for the positive button of the dialog
        addDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {

                Button saveButton = (Button) addView.findViewById(R.id.save_button);

                saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        // add wantToCloseDialog to prevent the dialog from closing when the information is not completely filled out
                        Boolean wantToCloseDialog = false;

                        EditText editHabitName = (EditText) addView.findViewById(R.id.habit_name);

                        EditText editNumberOfTimes = (EditText) addView.findViewById(R.id.number_of_times);

                        String name = editHabitName.getText().toString().trim();
                        String date = startDate.getText().toString().trim();
                        String frequency = editNumberOfTimes.getText().toString().trim();

                        // validate all the required infomation
                        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name)  || TextUtils.isEmpty(date) || TextUtils.isEmpty(frequency)) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.habit_info_not_complete), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else {
                            insertHabit(name, date, frequency);
                            wantToCloseDialog = true;
                        }

                        // after successfully inserting product, dismiss the dialog
                        if(wantToCloseDialog)
                            addDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        return addDialog;
    }

    private void insertHabit(String name, String date, String frequency){
        HabitDbHelper mHabitDbHelper = new HabitDbHelper(getActivity());
        SQLiteDatabase db = mHabitDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(HabitContract.HabitEntry.COLUMN_NAME, name);
        values.put(HabitContract.HabitEntry.COLUMN_START_DATE, date);
        values.put(HabitContract.HabitEntry.COLUMN_NUMBER_OF_TIMES, frequency);

        long newRowId = db.insert(HabitContract.HabitEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

        if (newRowId == -1) {
            // If the row ID is -1, then there was an error with insertion.
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.save_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            // Otherwise, the insertion was successful and we can display a toast with the row ID.
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.habit_saved, newRowId), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Post your code snippet

Comment: show xml please .

Comment: add java file too.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Added the xml in the description

Comment: post your code file along

Comment: @ChetanShankar Java code file added

Comment: try  `android:inputType="numberDecimal"` instead of  android:inputType="number"

Comment: @PallaviTapkir I tried that but same issue persisted. There seems to be some issue only with input from numerical styled keypad

Comment: @UtkarshTiwari if you change input type TEXT then ?? for test case

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Input type 'TEXT' seems to work fine as you can see in the image, the EditText for habit name accepts input from qwerty keyboard but the one for 'Number of Times' doesn't

Comment: use `android:inputType="phone" android:digits="0123456789"`

Comment: you can use  android:digits=`"0123456789"`. and also check on some another device.

Answer (score 0):

Take `android:weightSum:"8"` in `LinearLayout`. It will be solve your problem.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum:"8"
android:orientation="vertical">

.......

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be already is late but here I write solution that helped for me. For me, I added in onResume() method

```
dialog?.setOnKeyListener { _, _, _ ->
        false
    }
```

and all work fine)

Here my thought about it: When we input text in EditText - setOnKeyListener is not detect keyEvent, but when we input number in EditText (this case happened when we set android:inputType="number" in EditText in layout), then setOnKeyListener is detecting keyEvent. I think because setOnKeyListener detect special keyEvent - this is main reason why you can not write number in EditText field.